# Mapstruct only load lazy field if I need

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, mapstruct

I using GraphQL with Spring Boot and mapstruct.

The problem if when I do the DTO, MapStruct map all fields, including lazy fields that maybe I don't need because with GraphQL I don't request them.

They are any way to ignore field in runtime with Mapstruct?

Anything that:

```kotlin
fun toDto(user: User, fieldsToMap: List<String>): UserDTO
```

Comment: Do you want ignored fields to be null in DTO? Or completely remove from the DTO fields?

Comment: Neither. I want keep as "proxy". So, if graphql use return them (with query to DDBB), and if graphql don't use, not query them.

Comment: There's  no point in doing that a DTO is final and should represent what the client needs, no more no less. It can't maintain proxies to things you might want. I would revisit your dto design to be more efficient.